# Are all current SE policies in the Help Center?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, help-center, policy

As we know, all users should follow the SE policies, so all policies should be easily accessible to all users. I think the only place one can find them is the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help). So, the following question may arise:

Are **all current** SE policies included in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)?

#### My Attempt

Please note that the following is just an instance of policies(?) which I cannot find in the Help Center.

Some people have told me there exists the policy of "Not Bumping Old Posts", which I cannot find by searching in the Help Center.

Are there some unwritten policies? If so, why are they not written in the Help Center?

Comment: The "don't bump old posts" isn't an official policy, part of the culture, so it has no place in the official pages.

Comment: Bumping old posts is fine, if you have something useful to say.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and in case of doing clean-up on a tag you might want to rate-limit your edits as not to flood the entire frontpage.

Comment: @Later I already pointed you to a community FAQ for SO where it is written down in a comment on your earlier chameleon question. Why ask again?

Comment: @Tufkamt This question is about Stack Exchange. Please note that this post is my only one about this subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are **all current** SE policies included in the Help Center?

Generally, yes. Behaviorally speaking, the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) and the [Expected Behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) entries in the Help Center are general guidelines when interacting on the site. Following the ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) entries will help with general knowledge on how to contribute your knowledge to your chosen site.

The example "policy" you mentioned has more to do with general accepted behavior than a written rule. Speaking of which, the "don't bump old posts" guidance could be more accurately written as "don't *unjustifiably* bump old posts." If you have a substantial edit or well-written answer, then there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to bump an older post with that action.

> Are there some unwritten policies? If so, why are they not written in the Help Center?

Well... There aren't really any unwritten *policies*, per se. There are just some general guidelines frequent contributors and moderators would prefer users followed while contributing. Sometimes this is called "etiquette".

As an example, if you're frequently editing your own question to "bump" it to the top of the Active list, and you're doing so persistently, a moderator or higher-reputation user might kindly ask you to make more substantial edits before doing so again. This isn't because they don't care for your edits or your question, rather they would prefer you didn't bump your post very frequently. They also would hope that you got your question or answer's content [right the first (or third, or seventeenth) time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28497).

Normalized behavior like this isn't defined in the Help Center because, depending upon the norm, it varies by site. More often than not, it's talked about in that site's [Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). [Drones and Model Aircraft](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) was recently created, and they've routinely had discussions about how to handle [various behavior](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/305), how to guide [newer users on editing correctly](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/96/305), and other topics.

To wrap it up, the Help Center's policies provide a global guideline for participating on the site. Per-site etiquette is something learned over time as you become more familiar with the sites in question. If you do something frowned upon, don't sweat it, simply correct it in the future. We don't hold grudges here.

Answer (score 6):

Well - one will find other than *formal* rules, as per the help center, communities often have informal ones that are driven by common sense.

Rather than saying "its not in the rules" - its worth thinking about why *needless* bumping of a post might be frowned upon. If an edit (and that's what bumps a post) is substantial, no one's going to complain. The system also sometimes automatically bumps question for attention.

People will get annoyed if someone *constantly* bumps their own post for attention with many trivial edits (or constant rollbacks) or if they flood the front page with edits (since many users rely on the front/latest page to keep track of their sites).

Essentially the biggest unwritten rule is to be mindful of the needs of other users.

Practically the very nature of unwritten rules is they're unwritten. You'll pick them up along the way, but they're too trivial, or amorphous, or are not a good fit for "formal" rules.

Answer (score 3):

I have received "No bump old post" comments from few OPs who are not interested anymore on their old questions and get mad for seeing one of them being bumped up.

If you receive such comments rarely don't worry at all, but if you are receiving those comments from different users "regularly" I suggest to ask on the specific meta for feedback about the type of edits you are doing.

NOTE: Only edit posts that are interesting to you either because their content or tags.